# Augment an interface to remove the indexer

Tags: typescript-typings

In @types/node the `NodeJS.ProcessEnv` interface is declared with an indexer:

```js
interface ProcessEnv {
    [key: string]: string | undefined;
}
```

And I'm augmenting it with my defined properties:

```js
declare module NodeJS {
    interface ProcessEnv {
        NODE_ENV: 'development' | 'production';
    }
}
```

It successfully type-checks the *value* of `process.env.NODE_ENV`, but it still allows any *property*. If I use the wrong property name (e.g. `MODE_ENB`), it doesn't produce an error, because of the indexer.

Is there a way to apply module augmentation to an interface that effectively removes an indexer?

---

#### Failed Attempts:

```js
        [key: string]: never;
        NODE_ENV: 'development' | 'production';
```

Error: Property 'NODE_ENV' of type '"development" | "production"' is not assignable to string index type 'never'.ts(2411)

```js
        [key: Exclude<string, 'NODE_ENV'>]: never;
        NODE_ENV: 'development' | 'production';
```

Error: An index signature parameter type cannot be a type alias. Consider writing '[key: string]: never' instead.ts(1336)

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution is to use:

```js
        [key: string]: unknown;
```

Which will prevent other properties from being assigned to known types:

```js
const env: string = process.env.NODE_ENVtypo;
// Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'. ts(2322)
```

But will still preserve the type of your defined properties:

```js
const env: string = process.env.NODE_ENV;
```

But it won't catch when comparing values:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENVZZZ === 'production') { // no error appears
```